# How to use styled along with theme in React/Next?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, themes, styled-components

I want to use a styled text field in my form. I am defining the override style with:

```
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
    '& label': {
      color: theme.palette.text.highlightText,
    },
    '& label.Mui-focused': {
      color: theme.palette.text.highlightText,
      borderRadius: '10px',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.default,
      borderRadius: '10px',
    },
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
      '& fieldset': {
        borderColor: 'transparent',
      },
      '&:hover fieldset': {
        borderColor: theme.palette.text.highlightText,
        borderRadius: '10px',
      },
      '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
        borderColor: theme.palette.text.highlightText,
        borderRadius: '10px',
      },
    },
  });
```

Now, if I define this INSIDE the parent component, the text field loses focus every time I type something.

I resolved this issue moving the styled bit OUTSIDE the parent component (as per documentation), but in that way I don't have access anymore the `theme` I define at the beginning the component.

Does anyone know how to use styled and theme at the same time? Because I can access `theme` while the styled text field is defined inside the parent, but I need to move it outside to avoid the focus bug.

Thanks everyone!